# How to execute different long-running tasks on different hosts at the same time in fabric?

Tags: python, python-2.7, fabric

i'm pretty new to fabric and i'm trying to create a script which starts three different servers and a client, but it seems it halts at the first task. here is my code:

```
env.user='userX'
env.roledefs = {
'client':['HostC'],
'id 0':['Host0'],
'id 1':['Host1'],
'id 2':['Host2']
}

def go():
execute(serve0)
execute(serve1)
execute(serve2)
execute(req)

@roles('id 0')
def serve0():
run('./go/bin/kvsd -id 0 -config-file ~/go/src/github.com/userX/kvs/kvsd/conf/config.ini')

@roles('id 1')
def serve1():
run('./go/bin/kvsd -id 1 -config-file ~/go/src/github.com/userX/kvs/kvsd/conf/config.ini')

@roles('id 2')
def serve2():
run('./go/bin/kvsd -id 2 -config-file ~/go/src/github.com/userX/kvs/kvsd/conf/config.ini')

@roles('client')
def req():
run('./go/bin/kvsc -config-file ~/go/src/github.com/userX/kvs/kvsc/config.ini')
```

I run it with "fab go", but that only leads to it executing serve0, which doesn't stop without an interupt, and as such prevents any of the other tasks from executing. Is there a way to make them run in parallel?  Also, is there a better way to tie spesific tasks to spesific hosts?

Answer (score 0):

Add the `@parallel` decorator to your functions and they will automatically run in parallel. More details here: http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/usage/parallel.html

Use `-H` when calling fabric from the cli to identify which hosts to use. From within the task you can check the `env` dictionary, or you can use the `@hosts` decorator to specify what runs where. More info here: http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/usage/execution.html

Comment: i'm testing parallel, by using a tiny scritp:
    @parallel
    def go():
    print "current host: %s" % env.host_string
but this gives me a EOFerror, it works for single host when i remove    the parallel decorator

Comment: That error sounds like there's a mismatched quote or something.